# How to change percentage query loader with text

Tags: jquery

How to change percentage (...%) [query loader](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/) with **text** example "**loading**"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set bool percentage as false options to loader.

```
bool percentage:Set to false.
```

Updated:

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function(){
$('#qLpercentage').html('loading');
$('#qLpercentage').css('background-image','url');//setting background image
},100)
$("body").queryLoader2();
});
```

Comment: Ok, but how to change with "loading", its my question and not to remove percentage!

Comment: @john:can u create the fiddle for same.

Comment: Milind : i already hack in its javascript and use static text,,, another question, how to remove "if (obj.css("background-image") != "none")" so I no need use background image in my css???

Comment: Milind: yes. currently i need use background image in css to use preloader. how to hack so i no need use background image?

Comment: Try using `setInterval($('#qLpercentage').css('background-image','url'),100)`

Comment: thanks for answer my question, last question how to center the text "Loading" ??? Because I check on my phone its not center?? THanks

Comment: Try adding this css same way using jquery in above code `text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 90px;       /* the same as your div height */`

Comment: $('#qLpercentage').css('text-align: center','vertical-align: middle', 'line-height: 90px'); //correct?

Comment: .css({
   'text-align': 'center',
   'vertical-align': middle',
  'line-height': '90px'
});

Comment: Milind : I already test but still see pull right on my mobile,,,

Comment: Milind : could you help please?

Comment: not till i get the environment for that. can you create fiddle.will try testing it on mobile.

Comment: Milind : sorry for long time for reply... http://jsfiddle.net/ehMVu/1/  I think on mobile we can't use same qLpercentage font size [for ex: 29 px] and its become not center and become <br> for example use 'Loading ...' so the result become 'Loading<br>...'.. any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `doc ready` handler:

```
$(function(){
     $("body").queryLoader2({
         ................
     });

    $('#qLpercentage').text('Loading'); //<---put it here
});
```

Comment: @john this is confusing plz elaborate more about it.

Comment: jai : i already hack in its javascript and use static text,,, another question, how to remove "if (obj.css("background-image") != "none")" so I no need use background image in my css???